# Using CEFSharp ILifeSpanHandler interface to Handle Popups

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have an issue with handling popups. I have implemented ILifeSpanHandler and OnBeforeBrowse (amoungst others) from the IRequestHandler.

How do I know in the ILifeSpanHandler what URL is being called? I am unable to get it in either the OnAfterCreated or OnBeforePopup. Currently I see it first in OnBeforeBrowse.

I have no code as my question is a "How to".  In OnBeforePopup I have checked targetUrl however it seems to be there for decoration as I have read that it is not implemented anyway.  I have also looked at the browner/chromiumWebBrowser objects, browser and newBroswer seem to be nothing.  One would expect in OnAfterCreated chromiumWebBrowser would return an object but it is nothing in my case.

I am testing with the following

```
        Public Sub OnAfterCreated(chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser) Implements ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated

            Try
                Debug.Print(vbNewLine)
                Debug.Print("OnAfterCreated")
                Debug.Print(String.Concat("OnAfterCreated - MainFrame.Url "), browser.MainFrame.Url)
                Debug.Print("OnAfterCreated")
                Debug.Print(vbNewLine)

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

And I have the following

```
 Public Function OnBeforePopup(chromiumWebBrowser As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, targetUrl As String, targetFrameName As String, targetDisposition As WindowOpenDisposition, userGesture As Boolean, popupFeatures As IPopupFeatures, windowInfo As IWindowInfo, browserSettings As IBrowserSettings, ByRef noJavascriptAccess As Boolean, ByRef newBrowser As IWebBrowser) As Boolean Implements ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup

            Try
                Debug.Print(vbNewLine)
                Debug.Print("OnBeforePopup")
                Debug.Print(String.Concat("OnBeforePopup - targetUrl "), targetUrl)
                Debug.Print(String.Concat("OnBeforePopup - browser.MainFrame.Url "), browser.MainFrame.Url)
                Debug.Print(String.Concat("OnBeforePopup - chromiumWebBrowser.Address "), chromiumWebBrowser.Address)
                Debug.Print("OnBeforePopup")
                Debug.Print(vbNewLine)
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try

            Return False
        End Function
```

Comment: Ask one question at a time please.

Comment: Also please update your question to show what you've attempted so far.

Comment: Ok lets make it 2 questions. They do deal both with popups but right now I cannot identify them so no point knowing how to close them yet.

Comment: Where did you read `targetUrl` is not implemented? `targetUrl` may be blank if the `window` was opened by javascript `window.open`

Comment: I had trouble finding it, but I think this here is what I read. https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=196 and https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromiumembedded/issues/5 it is however very out of date.

Comment: Those links are so out of date. Open https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target in the browser, click the `visit w3schools` link and see what you get for `targetUrl`.

Comment: added my test code to the original post.  targetURL with w3schools is still an empty string.

Comment: What version of `CefSharp` are you using?

Comment: I am getting it with nuget and I believe it is 69. I am using it in a WPF project.

Comment: Testing with https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and adding a very basic `ILifeSpanHandler` implementation and I get `targetUrl` as expected. `OnAfterCreated` is too early to be accessing the `MainFrame`. Check the `Frame.Identifier` and you'll know if it's valid, read http://cefsharp.github.io/api/67.0.0/html/P_CefSharp_IFrame_Identifier.htm

Comment: My bad. The above code is formatted incorrectly. Once I worked out that, i am getting the url.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen different approaches in handling popups using ILifeSpanHandler interface. One approach that I've seen also here in Stack Overflow and was accepted as the correct answer to that particular question is to return true in the OnBeforePopup implementation of ILifeSpanHandler then pass the targetURL argument to a handler that creates the popup.

This approach is very unideal because you are destroying the link between the page that actually opened the popup and the popup itself. If you access via JavaScript the opener property of the window object inside the popup you would notice that it is null. And the page that opened the popup would never know that the popup was actually opened because returning true cancels the creation.

The other approach is to let Cef create the popup and the programmer just decides whether to show the browser as a popup window or a child to control (like in tabbed browsing). This is error-free and almost ideal. But the problem with this approach is that you are not able to listen to events such as FrameLoadStart, FrameLoadEnd, AddressChanged, TitleChanged, etc.

One approach that is tagged experimental by the Cef developers is to return a new IWebBrowser instance via newWebBrowser out parameter. This has so many many side effects. The page that opened the popup would, of course, recognize the popup as his although it was not the original browser (IBrowser) that it created. The page may just ignore it like btcclicks.com and in that case, there'd be no problem. But there are websites like `drops.xyz` that is so particular with his stuff and will discard everything that is not originally his. So this is a problem.

So what is the correct approach?

**The ChromeWebBrowser** control

Now I'm going to share with you an undocumented approach in handling popups. Speaking of ChromeWebBrowser control, it is very much of help that we know how it creates the webbrowser which, in reality, it doesn't. The control just hosts the webbrowser window handle. It has a private field called managedCefBrowserAdapter (ManagedCefBrowserAdapter class) that handles the actual creation of the web browser. ChromiumWEbBrowser implements the IWebBrowserInternal that has a method OnAfterBrowserCreated with a single parameter of type IBrowser. The control then invokes `browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle()` to get the actual window handle (HWND) of the webbrowser it is being hosted. It is quite good.

The problem of the ChromeWebBrowser is that it won't have a constructor that accepts an IBrowser as an argument. It only has constructor that accepts HtmlString, string and IRequestContext arguments. These control waits for the
invocation of OnHandleCreated (a base class override) where it calls the managedCefBrowserAdapter.CreateBrowser after which it waits till its implementation of IWebBrowserInternal's OnAfterBrowserCreated is invoked.

**Again, what is the approach that works?**

Now, this approach that actually works is a product of long series of trial and error. One caution though is that I don't know why and how it works but I know it works.

First, I did not use ChromeWebBrowser. But I copied its code omitting the part where it creates .net control. In this case, I am targeting the browser's window handle (HWND) to be host by any object that exposes a HWND. Obviously I created a class (NativeCefWebBrowser) that uses the modified code. The ChromeWebBrowser orignal constructors were still there untouched becuase they are used to the create the parent webrowser. But I added one constructor that accept the following arguments: ICefBrowserParent parent (an interface I've created and IBrowser browser that receives the browser argument in the ILifeSpanHandler's OnBeforePopup. I also added a public method AttachBrowser that has a single parameter IBrowser that recieves the IBrowser argument in the ILifeSpanHandler's OnAfterCreated. It the browser that will be kept by CefNativeWebBrowser class.

Why didn't I keep the browser instance received form ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup but used the instance received from ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated when they are the same browser instance? This is one of those parts that I don't know why. One thing I noticed is that when I called browser.GetHost().GetWindowHandle() during ILiffeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup, the first window handle I received was the different compared to when I invoked the method during ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreatd. Because of that, I store the browser instance from the latter that I passed to the NativeCefWebBrowser.AttachBrowser for its safekeeping.

In the NativeCefWebBrowser(ICefBrowserParent parent, IBrowser browser) contructor, I set the private following fields to true: browsercreated, browserinitialized (chromewebbrwoser orginal fields) and isAttachingBrowser (added private field). You don't call the ManagedCefBrowserAdapter's CreateBrowser in this contructor in instead call its OnAfterBrowserCreated passing the browser instance. You don't much in this constructor as you will wait the ILifeSpanHandler implementor to pass you the browser instance it will receive during its OnAfterCreated method. Take note that when calling the ManagedCefBrowserAdapter's OnAfterBrowserCreated method, ManagedCefBrowserAdapter will still invoke IWebBrowserInternal implementation of OnAfterBrowserCreated that when happens you have to exit immediately when isAttachingBrowser is true as the following code will no sense no more.

After calling the NativeCefWebBrowser(ICefBrowserParent, IBroser) construct, you can normally set event listeners as you will normally do.

And that's it.

The following are parts of the code that I wrote

**The ICefBrowserParent interface**

```
public interface ICefBrowserParent
{
    IntPtr Handle { get; }
    Size ClientSize { get; }
    bool Disposing { get; }
    bool IsDisposed { get; }
    bool InvokeRequired { get; }
    IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(Delegate d);
    object Invoke(Delegate d);
    event EventHandler Resize;
}
```

As you would notice, the methods, properties and events in this interface are already implemented by the System.Windowns.Forms.Control class. So if you implementing this from class inhering Control class, you would not need to implement this anymore. This interface is only for non-Control class.

```
class NativeCefWebBrowser
{
    public NativeCefWebBrowser(ICefBrowserParent, IBroser)
    {
        requestContext = browser.GetHost().RequestContext;
        this.parent = parent; // added field
        HasParent = true;     // IWebBrowserInternal. I don't know what's this for
        mustSetBounds = true; // added field
        browserCreated = true;
        isAttachingBrowser = true; // added field
        InitializeFieldsAndCefIfRequired();
        managedCefBrowserAdapter.OnAfterBrowserCreated(browser);
    }
}

ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup(..., out IWebBrowser newWebBrowser)
{
    CefNativeWebBrowser b = new CefNativeWebBrowser
    (
        parent, // defined else where
        browser
    );
    // Attach event handlers
    b.TitleChanged...;
    newWebBrowser = b;
}

ILifeSpanHandler.OnAfterCreated(...)
{
    ((CefNativeWebBrowser)webBrowser).AttachBrowser(browser);
}
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly and I'm not exactly sure that I am as your example is incomplete, the fact you are setting HasParent = true is likely going to cause the incorrect IBrowser instance being returned in some cases. For popups the events aren't called deliberately,  you can use the handlers http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_IDisplayHandler.htm http://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_ILoadHandler.htm if wish to call the events then as a workaround in your handler implementation cast IWebBrowser to IWebBrowserInternal and call the set method for each.

Comment: If there is a use case you'd like to see support added for then you are welcome to goto https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/new/choose and select feature request.

Comment: @amaitland As I have said I don't know what's the use of that. I also set it to false and I saw no difference. One reason I included that in my post is for someone to do some clear explanation regarding its use because until now, there is no documentation for IWebBrowserInternal interface, or maybe I just can't find it. But I have already googled it so many times. Regarding events not being called deliberately on popups, no, they are. Using the implementation I posted, LoadEnd, LoadStart, AddressChanged among others are called.

Comment: There is no documentation, these methods are used internally,  look at the source for ClientAdapter. The source is on GitHub.  I'd strongly discourage your approach as you will likely get unexpected results when it comes to which IBrowser instance you are passed. I'm suggesting a workaround which is cleaner, easier to understand and less likely to break as it doesn't rely on the internal implementation. If you upgrade from version 86 to the newest 87 pre release your code won't compile. If your solution works for you, great, I'm strongly advising others don't attempt this. That's my opinion.

Comment: I am not insisting on the result of my experimentation. People may or may not use it. CefSharp authors too may use or not use it. As of now, what I care for is I made CefSharp work for me the way I like it. I actually didn't know CefSharp was already existing. I was still using the never-growing-up WebBrowser ActiveX control of windows until I typed in the google search bar: embeddable google chrome browser and hit the enter key.

Comment: I am the CefSharp maintainer and I'm suggesting you open a feature request and discuss your requirements.

Comment: I thought I overlooked those interfaces so I looked at my code and found out that I am already implementing them (IDisplayHandler and ILoadHandler). Yes, their methods are invoked but only for ChromeWebBrowser and never for the instance of IBrowser class that is in the OnBeforePopup and OnAfterCreated methods of the ILifeSpanHandler. So, I believe unless ChromeWebBrowser control is enabled so that it works with said IBrowser instance, there's no way you could attach FrameLoad and AddressChanged event listeners to IBrowser because it has no events in the first place. Maybe I shall github this.

Comment: The handlers should be called for all browsers, including popups. I'd suggest you download the source and add some breakpoints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227480/discussion-between-abet-and-amaitland).